# cherrypy serve multiple requests / per connection

Tags: stream, zip, cherrypy

i have this code
(on the fly compression and stream)

```
@cherrypy.expose
def backup(self):
    path = '/var/www/httpdocs'
    zip_filename = "backup" + t.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_") + ".zip"

    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % (zip_filename,)

    #https://github.com/gourneau/SpiderOak-zipstream/blob/3463c5ccb5d4a53fc5b2bdff849f25bae9ead761/zipstream.py
    return ZipStream(path)

backup._cp_config = {'response.stream': True}
```

the problem i faced is when i'm downloading the file i cant browse any other page or send any other request until the download done...
i think that the problem is that cherrypy can't serve more than one request at a time/ per user

any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say "per user", do you mean that another request could come in for a different "session" and it would be allowed to continue?

In that case, your issue is almost certainly due to session locking in cherrypy. You can read more about it is the [session code](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/b0c48210b250/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py). Since the sessions are unlocked late by default, the session is not available for use by other threads (connections) while the backup is still being processed.

Try setting `tools.sessions.locking = 'explicit'` in the _cp_config for that handler. Since you’re not writing anything to the session, it’s probably safe not to lock at all.

Good luck. Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what i need! Thanks a lot for your help and for your immediate response!

Comment: yet another good hint: http://blog.schmichael.com/2007/09/20/session-locking-and-performance-in-cherrypy/ you can simply release the session log, when not needed anmyore by issuing `cherrypy.session.release_lock()`

Answer (score 0):

Also, from the [FAQ](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/appendix/faq.html#server-features-and-configuration):

"CherryPy certainly can handle multiple connections. It’s usually your browser that is the culprit. Firefox, for example, will only open two connections at a time to the same host (and if one of those is for the favicon.ico, then you’re down to one). Try increasing the number of concurrent connections your browser makes, or test your site with a tool that isn’t a browser, like siege, Apache’s ab, or even curl."